# Trace/BPT trap with Python threading module

Tags: python, multithreading

The following code dies with `Trace/BPT trap`:

```
from tvdb_api import Tvdb
from threading import Thread

class GrabStuff(Thread):
    def run(self):
        t = Tvdb()

def main():
    threads = [GrabStuff() for x in range(1)]
    [x.start() for x in threads]
    [x.join() for x in threads]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error occurs due to the `Tvdb()`, but I have no idea why.

I ran the code with `python -m pdb thescript.py` and stepped through the code, and it dies at after the following lines:

```
> .../threading.py(468)start()
-> _active_limbo_lock.acquire()
(Pdb) 
> .../threading.py(469)start()
-> _limbo[self] = self
(Pdb) 
> .../threading.py(470)start()
-> _active_limbo_lock.release()
(Pdb) 
> .../threading.py(471)start()
-> _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
(Pdb) 
> .../threading.py(472)start()
-> self.__started.wait()
(Pdb) Trace/BPT trap
```

(I replaced the full path to threading.py with `...`)

The same problem occurs with `2.6.1` and `2.5.4`. The machine is running on OS X 10.6.1 Snow Leopard. The `tvdb_api` code can be found on [github.com/dbr/tvdb_api](http://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api)

Comment: https://github.com/dbr/tvdb_api is 404.  I had to change it to http.

Comment: The fact that there's a Rakefile (Ruby) inside this Python module makes me seriously question its sanity, but in any case I don't get any errors when I run the above code in Linux.  Try running it in a (real) debugger to see if you get a backtrace from the "Trace/BPT trap"; you could also try commenting out blocks of Tvdb.__init__ to see if you can narrow down the cause.

Comment: @Glenn: Heh, I don't see how using a Rakefile is any different from using a Makefile or shell scripts to automate deployments/etc.. I would have used Pyke or something Python'y, but none of them are installed by default on OS X (whereas rake is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad things can happen when importing modules for the first time in a thread on OS X 10.6.  See, for instance, [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7085).  As a workaround, try looking through Tvdb and add its complete chain of imports to the main module.

Comment: Strange.. Initialising Tvdb() once outside the thread (just under the import, or in `main()`) prevents the crash.. Thanks!