# Trace/BPT trap when calling urllib.urlopen

Tags: python, trace, urllib2, urllib, web.py

For some reason I'm getting a Trace/BPT trap error when calling `urllib.urlopen`. I've tried both `urllib` and `urllib2` with identical results. Here is the code which throws the error:

```
def get_url(url):
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    if not url or not url.startswith('http://'): return None
    return urlopen(url).read() # FIXME!
```

I should add that this code is running on a CherryPy webserver with web.py.

Someone requested a traceback. Unfortunately, there is none. `Trace/BPT trap` is outputted to the terminal and the process terminates. E.g.

```
dloewenherz@andros project $ sudo ./index.py 80
http://0.0.0.0:80/
# Here I visit the page which contains the get_url(url) method
Trace/BPT trap
dloewenherz@andros project $
```

Edit: I am running OS X 10.6.2, web.py 0.33, Python 2.6.2, and CherryPy 3.1.2.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd put in some portion of the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the top of the main file solved the problem:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener())
```

In other words, it is not enough to import the urllib2 module but you actually need to create the opener in the main thread.

Comment: Also, I can't seem to mark this as the answer. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Seems to be a threading issue with Snow Leopard caused by loading CoreFoundation on a background thread. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540835/trace-bpt-trap-with-python-threading-module/1547316#1547316

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this under OS X 10.6? Apparently threads and importing modules for the first time does not play well together there. See if you can't import urllib2 outside of the thread?

There are a few more details in the following thread: [Trace/BPT trap with Python threading module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540835/trace-bpt-trap-with-python-threading-module)

I'd try either moving the import of urllib to the top of the same file or, since it seems to be a problem only with importing a module for the first time in a thread, import it somewhere else as well, like in the same file as your main() function.

**Edit:** Which versions of OS X, Python, CherryPy and web.py are you running? I'm using OS X 10.5.8, Python 2.6, CherryPy 3.1.2 and web.py 0.33 and can't reproduce your problem using the below code:

```
import web

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:
    def GET(self):
        from urllib2 import urlopen
        return urlopen("http://google.se/").read()

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()


$ sudo python index.py 80
http://0.0.0.0:80/
127.0.0.1:59601 - - [08/Nov/2009 09:46:40] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
127.0.0.1:59604 - - [08/Nov/2009 09:46:40] "HTTP/1.1 GET /extern_js/f/CgJzdhICc2UgACswCjhBQB0sKzAOOAksKzAYOAQsKzAlOMmIASwrMCY4BSwrMCc4Aiw/dDWkSd2jmF8.js" - 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1:59601 - - [08/Nov/2009 09:46:40] "HTTP/1.1 GET /logos/elmo-hp.gif" - 404 Not Found
127.0.0.1:59601 - - [08/Nov/2009 09:46:40] "HTTP/1.1 GET /images/nav_logo7.png" - 404 Not Found
```

Is this code enough to reproduce the problem on your end? If not, I need more information in order to be of help.

Comment: Yep, I'm running 10.6.1. How would I go about importing the module outside of the thread?

Comment: Not knowing how the rest of the file looks, I'd try moving the import statement out of get_url() to the top of the file.

Comment: Just moved the import statement to the top. Still no dice.

Comment: Do you only have one python file — or several?

If you have several, which one contains your main() function? Is it the same one as the one you moved the import statement to the top of?

If not, also add the import statement to the file that contains your main() function.

Comment: I'll go ahead and try importing the module in the index.py file as well. I'll give an update when I do.

Comment: Absolutely no difference. Still crashes.

Comment: Paste the exception you're receiving.

Comment: @John Geo: Unfortunately hitting this problem gives no exception information.

Comment: Seems ubidr answered the question. Thanks though!